# After running multiple time with same code with same input size in Python 3.4 throw IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.5, quicksort, index-error, ubuntu-16.10

I am new to Python. I wrote a code for quick sort to sort integer numbers in ascending order. 
Using - Ubuntu 16.10 and python3.5

Code -

```
import random

a=[]
n=int(input("Enter size :\n"))
for i in range(0,n):
        a.append(int(random.randrange(0,100)))
print("Before Sorting:",a)

def quick(a,low,high):
        if(low<high):
                i=low
                j=high
                key=a[low]
                flag=1
                while (flag==1):
                        i += 1
                        while(a[i]<key):
                                i += 1
                        while (a[j]>key):
                                j -= 1
                        if (i<j):
                                a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i]
                        else:
                                flag=0
                a[low],a[j]=a[j],a[low]
                quick(a,low,j-1)
                quick(a,j+1,high)

# Calling function quick where a = List, 0 = Start Index ,n-1 = Last Index
quick(a,0,n-1)
print("After Sorting:",a)
```

When i run the code it throws IndexError: list index out of range  but if i run the same code with same input it gives correct output.
For example -
Running the code for 1st time with n = 5

```
linux@linux-Lenovo-G50-30:~/PYTHON/practice/run1$ python3 quick.py
Enter size :
5
Before Sorting : [55, 23, 57, 86, 20]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick.py", line 30, in <module>
   quick(a,0,n-1)
  File "quick.py", line 27, in quick
   quick(a,j+1,high)
  File "quick.py", line 17, in quick
   while(a[i]<key):
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Running the code for 2nd time with n = 5

```
Enter size :
5
Before Sorting : [6, 5, 93, 84, 32]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick.py", line 30, in <module>
    quick(a,0,n-1)
  File "quick.py", line 27, in quick
    quick(a,j+1,high)
  File "quick.py", line 17, in quick
    while(a[i]<key):
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Running the code for 3rd time with n = 5

```
linux@linux-Lenovo-G50-30:~/PYTHON/practice/run1$ python3 quick.py
Enter size :
5
Before Sorting : [87, 18, 94, 1, 64]
After Sorting : [1, 18, 64, 87, 94]
```

I am not able to figure out why this happens.
I am using Ubuntu 16.10 and python3.5

Comment: Problem is with your algo to sort! There is no problem in ubuntu 16.10 or python 3.5 . Your data is random so in some cases exception doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't is that you are setting up a random array of numbers. As your post shows, even with the same input data (length of list) the numbers are different every time. Your `quick()` function works with some input data and fails with other input data. It is failing because `a[i]<key` assumes that there are `i-1` elements in `a`, and depending on your data, sometimes there aren't.

The fix below makes your out-of-range error go away. I've run it a couple of dozen times and the results seem okay. I can't promise that the code is a correct implementation of Quicksort, though.

```
def quick(a,low,high):
        if(low<high):
                i=low
                j=high
                key=a[low]
                flag=1
                while (flag==1):
                        i += 1
                        while(i < len(a) and a[i]<key):
                                i += 1
                        while (j < len(a) and a[j]>key):
                                j -= 1
                        if (i<j):
                                a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i]
                        else:
                                flag=0
                a[low],a[j]=a[j],a[low]
                quick(a,low,j-1)
                quick(a,j+1,high)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

a=[]
n=int(input("Enter size :\n"))
for i in range(0,n):
    a.append(int(random.randrange(0,100)))
print("Before Sorting:",a)    

def sort(a):
    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []

    if len(a) > 1:
        pivot = a[0]
        for x in a:
            if x < pivot:
                less.append(x)
            if x == pivot:
                equal.append(x)
            if x > pivot:
                greater.append(x)
        return sort(less)+equal+sort(greater)
    else: 
        return a

a = sort(a)
print("After Sorting:",a)
```